# spring @resource inject NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, aop

I define an Aspect class `RedisAspect.java`:

```
 @Aspect
public class RedisAspect implements IAspect {

    private static String INTERFACE_COUNT = "interfaces";
    @Resource(name = "RedisDao")
    private IRedisDao redisDao;

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.xxx.web.service.xxxWebImpl.*.*(..))")
    public void servicePoint() {
    }

    /**
     * count all interfaces
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    @Before("servicePoint()")
    public void doBefor(JoinPoint point) throws Exception {
        String interfaceName = point.getSignature().getName();
        System.out.println("interfaceName : " + interfaceName);
        redisDao.addInterfaceCount(interfaceName);
    }

    @Override
    @After("servicePoint()")
    public void doAfter(JoinPoint point) {
        System.out.println("do After");
    }

    @Override
    public void doAterThrowing(Exception ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

follow is RedisDaoImpl.java:

```
@Component("RedisDao")
public class RedisDaoImpl extends AbstractBaseRedisDao<String, Integer> implements IRedisDao {

    private static String INTERFACES = "interfaces";
    @Override
    public void addInterfaceCount(final String index) throws Exception {
        redisTemplate.execute(new RedisCallback<Object>() {

            @Override
            public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection)
                    throws DataAccessException {
                connection.hIncrBy(INTERFACES.getBytes(), index.getBytes(), 1);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }

    public void delete(String index) {
        redisTemplate.delete(index);
    }


    @Override
    public void addFailedRequest(String index) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

then xml configuration

```
<bean id="redisAspect" class="com.xxx.web.aspect.RedisAspect"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.web.*" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

now before the login method(in `com.xxx.web.service.xxxWebImpl.UserServiceImpl.java`) is invoked, the `doBefor` method will be executed, but it shows me that `redisDao` is null.However when I try to directly invoke the `redisDao` in service, it seems ok, I am confused where I was wrong, wish someone can help me.

Comment: I just found something wired is that now everthing goes OK... I just put this line <bean id="redisAspect" class="com.xxx.web.aspect.RedisAspect"/> after <context:component-scan base-package="com.xxx.web.*" />, but I don't think this is the reason, becaues I put this line in front again, it also goes well.... so does   anyone know where I was wrong?